# Gtest: Undefined References

Tags: c++, unit-testing, unix, cmake, googletest

I am trying to use GoogleTest to test a simple function, but as I run `make` in my build folder, the compiler throws `Undefined Reference` error messages at me. I've referenced the gtest header file, so I'm not sure what is wrong. Any ideas? I'm new to the entire subject of both unix and unit testing , so I could very well be missing something simple. Thanks in advance!

Error Messages:

```
CMakeFiles/Proj2.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x1e): undefined reference to `testing::InitGoogleTest(int*, char**)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x23): undefined reference to `testing::UnitTest::GetInstance()'
main.cpp:(.text+0x2b): undefined reference to `testing::UnitTest::Run()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

main.cpp

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

Test.cpp

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include "Testable.h"

TEST(GetTwoTest, Two) {
    EXPECT_EQ(2, GetTwo());
}
```

Testable.cpp

```
#include "Testable.h"

int GetTwo() {
    return 3;
}
```

Here is my CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)

SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=gnu++11") #Turn on C++11 Support

set(FILES_TO_TEST Testable.cpp)
set(UNIT_TESTS Test.cpp)
set(MAIN_FILE main.cpp)

add_subdirectory(gtest) #Build all the gtest stuff
include_directories(gtest/include)
include_directories(.)
add_library(codeToTest ${FILES_TO_TEST})

add_executable(Proj2 ${MAIN_FILE})
target_link_libraries(Proj2 codeToTest)

add_executable(unit-test ${UNIT_TESTS})
target_link_libraries(unit-test gtest gtest_main rt pthread codeToTest)
```

Comment: Note that Google recommend that you DO NOT build a library, but instead include the GTest code into your project. See https://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/FAQ#Why_is_it_not_recommended_to_install_a_pre-compiled_copy_of_Goog

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your setup looks to be almost correct.  However, you're needing to have 2 separate `main` functions; one for the real executable `Proj2` and another with the gtest includes and functions for the test executable `unit-test`.

You could do this by having 2 different main.cpp files, say main.cpp and test_main.cpp.  The one you've shown would be test_main.cpp, and would be included in the `add_executable(unit-test ...` command.

Your new main.cpp would have no references to gtest, either includes or functions.

Comment: Thanks, that was my problem. I was using gtest_main in the CMakeLists file, so I just had to remove the gtest functions in my main.cpp.

Answer (score 4):

From linker errors it is obvious that you did not link gtest library to your test program.

See [Primer](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/primer.md):

> To write a test program using Google Test, you need to compile Google Test into a library and link your test with it. ...

Just see this doc for details about your compiler and system.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I read over the link you provided, but it seemed to skip right over the details on correctly linking the gtest Library (since I'm not using an IDE). I used CMake to generate the build files, so that's where the linking should take place, no? I provided my CMakeLists.txt file for further clarification

Comment: Follow this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8507723/how-to-start-working-with-gtest-and-cmake

Answer (score 1):

**Put the `libgtest.a` after your object files**

If you are doing things manually instead of with CMake, make sure to do:

```
g++ main.cpp googletest/build/lib/libgtest.a
```

instead of:

```
g++ googletest/build/lib/libgtest.a main.cpp
```

Here's a full working example I've tested with: https://askubuntu.com/questions/97626/how-to-install-googletest/1295185#1295185

This problem is not exclusive to GoogleTest: I can also reproduce it with a [minimal library example like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961446/why-does-gcc-not-implicitly-supply-the-fpic-flag-when-compiling-static-librarie/65005457#65005457) and [Eli explainss](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2013/07/09/library-order-in-static-linking) the ordering rules which I don't have the patience to learn right now.