# Entangled with Google test

Tags: android, c++, unit-testing, android-ndk, qt-creator

I am having trouble to get up and running with Google test. I have read the suggested [steps](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/primer.md) from Google, I also looked a previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12657596/gtest-undefined-references), and read some other [examples](http://wiki.ros.org/gtest), but it doesn't clear much things up.

To keep things simple, I am trying the suggested example from Google test that is available from the directory in the Android ndk - sample1:

// main.cpp

```
#include <QtGui/QGuiApplication>
#include "qtquick2applicationviewer.h"
#include "gtest/gtest.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);

    QtQuick2ApplicationViewer viewer;
    viewer.setMainQmlFile(QStringLiteral("qml/factorial/main.qml"));
    viewer.showExpanded();

    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

// sample1_unittest.cpp

```
#include <limits.h>
#include "sample1.h"
#include "gtest/gtest.h"

// Tests factorial of 0.
TEST(FactorialTest, Zero) {
  EXPECT_EQ(1, Factorial(0));
}
```

The files sample1.h, sample1.cpp are also in the project, which contain the factorial function. Google test was equally informed to the project file - factorial.pro:

```
INCLUDEPATH += 
/opt/android-studio/ndk/sources/third_party/googletest/googletest/include
```

When I press [Build > Build Project "factorial"] it gets the following error:

```
main.cpp:8: error: undefined reference to 'testing::InitGoogleTest(int*, char**)'
sample1_unittest.cpp:17: error: undefined reference to 'testing::Test::Test()'
```

I am working with Ubuntu, QtCreator, Android and C++. Indeed I have spent already 3 days mocking around, but getting not much anywhere so far. Thus, I am posting here in hope some guru may give any hint on this. Any help will be mostly appreciated.

Comment: Have you added gtest.lib\gtest.a to your link line?

Comment: @Wes - Just did: # find / -name gtest.a ... and nothing comes out. Any suggestion where it is supposed to be, or should gtest.a be build? Thanks!

Comment: Note that Google recommend that you DO NOT build a library, but instead include the GTest code into your project. See https://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/FAQ#Why_is_it_not_recommended_to_install_a_pre-compiled_copy_of_Goog

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems you haven't built Google Test from what you describe. You need to compile the project into a library and then link against it. If you have [CMake](http://www.cmake.org) installed, then you have two options:

- Use CMake's GUI (it's fairly intuitive) to generate the build system files, and then use those as usual (e.g. if you generate a Visual Studio solution, open the `.sln` file and build the project).
- Use the command line to do the same thing; essentially you just create a new directory and do `cmake <path-to-google-test>` inside of it. The rest is the same.

You could also build the library by yourself. The distribution contains a folder named `fused-src` which should contain at least two files: `gtest_main.cpp` and `gtest-all.cpp`. Compile those files and you're done. You need to generate two libraries here: `gtest` out of `gtest-all.cpp` and `gtest_main` out of `gtest_main.cpp`.

Another alternative would be to get already built libraries. I've never searched for them, but they might be out there.

Comment: No, I haven't built yet, as I read that it already comes with the Android-NDK. I looked for the files you mentioned. What I have with the Android NDK in the folder ./ndk/sources/third_party/googletest/googletest/src are following files : gtest_main.cc and gtest-all.cc, and there is also a gtest.cc in the same directory. I don't have CMake installed as I am using Qt Creator. I don't see any Make file in the src directory to compile/build it using g++. Do you suggest using CMake at least for building the gtest.cc? Thanks!

Comment: @JessicaCohen You have to compile `gtest-all.cc` into a library named `gtest` (you can name it whatever you want, but you get the idea), and `gtest_main.cc` into another named `gtest_main`. You can do this without CMake, although you might then miss threading support (which shouldn't be a great deal). I haven't used the distribution that comes with the Android NDK, so I don't know if it includes a CMakeLists.txt file. If you don't want to mess with CMake, simple do as I said: compile the previous files into two libraries and link against them.

Answer (score 5):

Try something like this:

```
$ g++ -I $GTEST_HOME/include -L $GTEST_HOME/lib -lgtest -lgtest_main -lpthread test.cpp
```

For more details:

- [How to setup googleTest as a shared library on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13513905/how-to-properly-setup-googletest-on-linux)

If it still doesn't work, may find interesting to consider to use Makefile:

```
# A sample Makefile for building Google Test and using it in user
# tests.  Please tweak it to suit your environment and project.  You
# may want to move it to your project's root directory.
#
# SYNOPSIS:
#
#   make [all]  - makes everything.
#   make TARGET - makes the given target.
#   make clean  - removes all files generated by make.

# Please tweak the following variable definitions as needed by your
# project, except GTEST_HEADERS, which you can use in your own targets
# but shouldn't modify.

# Points to the root of Google Test, relative to where this file is.
# Remember to tweak this if you move this file.
GTEST_DIR = ..

# Where to find user code.
USER_DIR = ../samples

# Flags passed to the preprocessor.
# Set Google Test's header directory as a system directory, such that
# the compiler doesn't generate warnings in Google Test headers.
CPPFLAGS += -isystem $(GTEST_DIR)/include

# Flags passed to the C++ compiler.
CXXFLAGS += -g -Wall -Wextra -pthread

# All tests produced by this Makefile.  Remember to add new tests you
# created to the list.
TESTS = sample1_unittest

# All Google Test headers.  Usually you shouldn't change this
# definition.
GTEST_HEADERS = $(GTEST_DIR)/include/gtest/*.h \
                $(GTEST_DIR)/include/gtest/internal/*.h

# House-keeping build targets.

all : $(TESTS)

clean :
    rm -f $(TESTS) gtest.a gtest_main.a *.o

# Builds gtest.a and gtest_main.a.

# Usually you shouldn't tweak such internal variables, indicated by a
# trailing _.
GTEST_SRCS_ = $(GTEST_DIR)/src/*.cc $(GTEST_DIR)/src/*.h $(GTEST_HEADERS)

# For simplicity and to avoid depending on Google Test's
# implementation details, the dependencies specified below are
# conservative and not optimized.  This is fine as Google Test
# compiles fast and for ordinary users its source rarely changes.
gtest-all.o : $(GTEST_SRCS_)
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) -I$(GTEST_DIR) $(CXXFLAGS) -c \
            $(GTEST_DIR)/src/gtest-all.cc

gtest_main.o : $(GTEST_SRCS_)
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) -I$(GTEST_DIR) $(CXXFLAGS) -c \
            $(GTEST_DIR)/src/gtest_main.cc

gtest.a : gtest-all.o
    $(AR) $(ARFLAGS) $@ $^

gtest_main.a : gtest-all.o gtest_main.o
    $(AR) $(ARFLAGS) $@ $^

# Builds a sample test.  A test should link with either gtest.a or
# gtest_main.a, depending on whether it defines its own main()
# function.

sample1.o : $(USER_DIR)/sample1.cc $(USER_DIR)/sample1.h $(GTEST_HEADERS)
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $(USER_DIR)/sample1.cc

sample1_unittest.o : $(USER_DIR)/sample1_unittest.cc \
                     $(USER_DIR)/sample1.h $(GTEST_HEADERS)
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $(USER_DIR)/sample1_unittest.cc

sample1_unittest : sample1.o sample1_unittest.o gtest_main.a
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -lpthread $^ -o $@
```

If you have to use Makefile to get gtest working, you probably may need to adjust the given [template](http://googletest.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/make/Makefile) for your case, as you intend to build it to use with Android.