# How do I make gtest work

Tags: c++, cmake, googletest, clion

So I'm getting `undefined reference to testing::UnitTest::Run()` along with some others with gtest. I've compiled the libraries (`libgtest.a` and `libgtest_main.a`) and placed them in my lib folder for MinGW and got no where.
Here is my `CMakeList.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)
project(proj_tests)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)

include_directories("E:/Git/proj")
include_directories("D:/Development/Libraries/gtest-1.7.0/include")

find_package(gtest REQUIRED)
include_directories(${GTEST_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_executable(proj_tests ${SOURCE_FILES} containers/proj_test.h)
target_link_libraries(proj_tests ${GTEST_LIBRARIES} pthread)
```

I have done `make` on the gtest sample and was able to run that without any issues.

I'm using CLion on Windows 7 for the project. How can I make this Google Test framework thing work properly?

Comment: So, what is the symptom?

Comment: I think the key is to understand what ``find_package(gtest REQUIRED)`` is finding. What is the value of ``${GTEST_LIBRARIES}``? For what it is worth, I am not aware of a standard way to find gtest as an external module because the gtest maintainers do not recommend using gtest this way--they suggest you build gtest with your sources rather than linking to an external library.

Comment: "undefined references" for my project.

Comment: @Phil: So dump the entire gtest src folder in the project?

Comment: Found similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12657596/gtest-undefined-references. Also, if you want to link with `libgtest_main.a`, you also need `GTEST_MAIN_LIBRARIES` variable (or just use `GTEST_BOTH_LIBRARIES`).

Comment: Thank you to all. These answers got me in the right direction for a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after a lot of hurt I switched to Linux and tried it there by downloading and compiling the `libgtest-dev` and using the configuration from Erik Smistad's [blog](http://www.eriksmistad.no/getting-started-with-google-test-on-ubuntu/). It worked within the CLion project without issues meaning something weird was happening to my Windows compiled Google Test library.

For windows/MinGW: Here is the solution I reached for Windows..

1. I got pre-compiled libraries from Richard Pattis's UCI [webpage](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~pattis/common/modules46/googletest.html) on how to get the google test framework to work on eclipse.
2. the `gtest` folder in `include` was copied to the `mingw32\include` folder,
3. the `gtest_main.a` and `libgtest.a` files from the `make` folder files were copied to `mingw32\lib` folder.

The final working CMake configuration looks like this for me:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)
project(eadlib_tests)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)

#path to project to test
include_directories("E:/Git/eadlib")

#Google test framework stuff
find_package(GTest REQUIRED)
include_directories(${GTEST_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(eadlib_tests ${SOURCE_FILES} containers/eadlib_test.h)
target_link_libraries(eadlib_tests ${GTEST_LIBRARIES} pthread)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you build gtest, you should have the following three files:

- include_fused/gtest/gtest.h
- include_fused/gtest/gtest-all.cc
- include_fused/gtest/gtest_main.cc

If you are providing your own main you just need the first two. If you want to use the gtest main, you need the third one too. The recommendation is to add these to each unit test project that you are building.

Answer (score 0):

like this (here's a snippet from one of my library projects)

```
find_package(GTest REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(cpputil_test cpputil ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT} ${GTEST_BOTH_LIBRARIES} ${Boost_LIBRARIES} )
add_test(NAME cpputil_test COMMAND cpputil_test)
```

Of course in my case the project is called cpputil_test. You'll need to replace it with your own.

Note also the use of `CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT` which allows your code to be portable across all host systems. It hides the dependency on `pthreads` when building for linux (OSX, iOS and Windows for example, do not have this dependency).