# Build static Library with -fPIC or -fPIE

Tags: linux, gcc, static-libraries

If I want to create a static library for everyone to use, is it necessary compile it with -fPIC or -fPIE?

It is working for me without -fPIC or -fPIE.

Comment: No. You can do it but it isn't very useful. One case when you might want to do it is letting your users build their own shared libraries based on your static lib.

Comment: Maybe see https://stackoverflow.com/q/5311515/1741542 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/3961446/1741542

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want your library to be linkable into shared libraries, position-dependent and position-independent executables. The only flag which works in all of these cases is `-fPIC` so that's the one you should use.