# Does 32bit x86 code need to be specially PIC-compiled for shared library files?

Tags: c, linux, shared-libraries, elf, pic

Compiling code to an object file needs to be done position-independent if the object file is intended to be loaded as a shared library (`.so`), because the base virtual address that the shared object file is loaded into in different processes may be different.

Now I didn't encounter errors when I tried to load an `.so` file compiled and linked without the `-fpic` GCC option on 32bit x86 computers, while it fails on 64bit bit x86 computers.

Random websites I found say that I don't need `-fpic` on 32bit because code compiled without `-fpic` works by coincidence according to the X86 32bit ABI also when used in a position-independent manner. But I still found software that ship with separate versions of libraries in their 32bit versions: One for PIC, and one for non-PIC. For example, the intel compiler ships with `libirc.a` and `libirc_pic.a`, the latter being compiled for position-independent mode (if one wants to link that `.a` file into an `.so` file).

I wonder what the precise difference between using `-fpic` and not using it is for 32bit code, and why some packages, like the intel compiler, still ship with separate versions of libraries?

Comment: Did you try non -fpic compile of code using TLS? Or load several non-pic libraries with overlapping memory ranges?  Separate static libs are to link into programs statically (libirc.a; no pic is a bit faster) and into .so libraries statically (_pic.a version).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3146744/difference-in-position-independent-code-x86-vs-x86-64

Answer (score 10):

It's not that non-PIC code works "by coincidence" on x86 (32-bit). It's that the dynamic linker for x86 supports the necessary "textrels" needed to make it work. This comes at a very high cost in memory consumption and startup time, since basically the entire code segment must be patched up at load time (and thus becomes non-shareable memory).

The dynamic linker maintainers claim that non-PIC shared libraries can't be supported on x86_64 because of fundamental issues in the architecture (immediate address displacements can't be larger than 32-bit) but this issue could be easily solved by just always loading libraries in the first 4gb of virtual address space. Of course PIC code is very inexpensive on x86_64 (PIC isn't a performance-killer like it is on 32-bit x86) so they're probably right to keep it unsupported and prevent fools from making non-PIC libraries...

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. If I compile a PIC lib on x86, it does not use textrels anymore, I suspect? Why is it still a performance-killer then?

Comment: PIC code requires an extra register to hold the base address. On x86 you already have too few registers, so reserving one more makes the compiler spill registers to memory even more often.

Comment: PIC is a performance-killer on x86 because loading the GOT register is expensive. It requires a function call and reading/saving the return address off the stack. x86_64 has `eip`-relative addressing making it so no GOT register is needed.

Comment: Also what Employed Russian said.

Comment: Ah I see now. I think for large libraries that don't need to run particularly fast, I better take the `_pic.a` version (because that won't require relocating `.text`). For small libs that need to run fast I will take the non-pic version and let it do the textrel.

Comment: You can have a shared non pic library for x86_64 with -mcmodel=large (and a recent enough gcc)

Comment: @R.. Interesting explanation. From my understanding, non-PIC libraries consumes memory and processing, but just during startup. Afterwards, it gets faster (because one machine register is freed). Therefore, if startup overhead is not an issue, is it better to use non-PIC libraries in x86 (32-bit) machines?

Comment: @Alek: Still non-PIC libraries will consume a lot more memory, and they'll be faster than PIC but not as fast as static linking because function calls will go through the PLT. For libraries where performance matters that much (like `libavcodec` or `libx264`) I would just avoid generating `.so` libraries so the library always ends up static-linked into the main program binary.

Answer (score 0):

> the base virtual address that the shared object file is loaded into in different processes ***may*** be different

Because shared objects usually load at their preferred address, they may appear to work correctly.  But `fPIC` is a good idea for all shared code.

I believe the reason that there aren't often two versions of the library is that many distributions use `fPIC` as the default for all code.

Comment: Shared objects are usually linked to load at address 0, and they most definitely do not load there.

Comment: What @Employed Russian said. Also, you may `prelink` libraries to make  them have a preferred base address, but it is a separate (and optional) step from normal linking.

Comment: @Employed Russian: Is that a linux-only thing?  Other OSes aren't so stupid as to default to 100% base address conflicts.

Comment: @Ben how is this an OS thing at all? It seems to be impossible to coordinate all the authors of libraries that a random program uses to use non-overlapping addresses ranges. How do the authors know about each other libraries?

Comment: @Johannes: Keyword "usually".  The address space is quite large compared to the code segment sizes, so conflicts are rare.  It's basically a birthday problem, but when you discount JIT compilation (which can dynamically pick an unused address) and libraries provided by the OS vendor (which can be carefully packed not to conflict), few programs load more than half-a-dozen third-party libraries.

Comment: Every UNIX linker I know of (except HP-UX/ia64 one) links shared libraries to load at 0 by default, and very few application programmers ever change the default. The Microsoft linker defaults to 0x10000000. You can modify this with a post-link step (prelink on Linux, REBASE on Win32). REBASE is used much more commonly then prelink, because UNIX loaders do function resolution lazyly, and few UNIX apps use lots of shared libraries.

Comment: @Employed: And right you are about 0x10000000.  Don't know why I thought that Visual C++ chose a random address and passed it to the linker.  Maybe some earlier version did that, but no longer.  Still, the majority of DLLs have non-default base addresses (run Dependency Walker on any application on your system to see).

Comment: Anyway, with Vista ASLR, rebasing only needs to be done once each time the computer is booted (and a random address is used, which reduces collisions).