# why cannot use R_X86_64_PC32 with shared libs

Tags: linker, shared-libraries, x86-64, elf

It seems to not be possible to build a shared lib from relocable objects with `R_X86_64_PC32` references and I don't understand why.

These references are IP relative and so are position independent. So why ld tell me this is not the case and I have to use `-fPIC` which generate a GOT reference ?

```
relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `infolib' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is said here : [Difference in position-independent code: x86 vs x86-64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3146744/difference-in-position-independent-code-x86-vs-x86-64?rq=1)

> IP-relative offset does not work for shared libraries, because global symbols can be overridden, so x86-64 breaks down when not built with PIC.

We have to use -fPIC to go through GOT which is updated at runtime for symbol overriding.

Comment: Or you can make your internal symbol references use "hidden" ELF visibility, so they're protected from symbol interposition and *can* use normal `call rel32` for functions and RIP-relative addressing for private static data (C `static` keyword, as opposed to globals).  You can make "hidden" aliases for global symbols so you can efficiently can functions inside your library; glibc does that in its own source code.  (often with a `weakref` attribute)

Comment: IIRC, GCC has an option to make the default symbol visibility "hidden", so you have to manually mark global vars and functions you want to be "exported" from your shared library.